# android.view.windowmanager Bad TokenException:unable to add window for Dialog on android

Tags: android, android-dialog

In my app i am showing a custom dialog from a non-activity class. it works but rarely crashed with the following reason:

```
android.view.windowmanager Bad TokenException:unable to add window-
token android.os.binderproxy@2afac69d8 is not valid;is your activity running?
```

my coding structure:

```
 MainActivity.java(Activity class)

 public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ........
            UpdateClass obj = new UpdateClass(MainActivity.this);
            obj.checkUpdate(); 
      }
 }
```

UpdateClass.java (Non Activity class)

```
public class UpdateClass{

UpdateClass(MainActivity mainActivity ){
  this.context = mainActivity;
}

checkUpdate(){

    dialog_Update = new Dialog(context);
    ...
    updateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        ....
        }
    });
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog_Update.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog_Update.show();  
   ......               
 } 
}
```

Comment: Is your activity visible on the screen when this code is called?

Comment: yes the MainActivity is visible when Dialog is appear.

Comment: no it is not. in onCreate, the tabActivity has not been added to the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to implement as below :

> ```
> public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
> @Override
>  private Context context;
>  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
>   {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         ........
>       context=MainActivity.this;
>         UpdateClass obj = new UpdateClass(context);
>         obj.checkUpdate(); 
>   }
> ```
>
> }

Do the changes as below in your `UpdateClass`.
Instead of passing the `MainActivity` in constructor pass the `Activity` as below:

> ```
> public class UpdateClass{
>     pdateClass(Activity mainActivity ){ <----Pass the activity here.
>     this.context = mainActivity;
>   }
>      ......               
>   } 
>  }
> ```